# Surround selection with method call

Tags: eclipse

Often when I'm writing code I forget to surround a section of code with a method.  For example, when printing an array, I realize that I forgot to pass the array into `Arrays.toString()`.

```java
String[] foo(){
    return new String[3];
}

main() {
    System.out.println(foo());
}
```

Is there a way in Eclipse that I can select `foo()` and then use auto complete or something to surround it with `Arrays.toString()`?  So I want to end up with this:

```java
main() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo()));
}
```

I know I could use templates, but I would have to make a template for each method I want to use.  I'm looking for something like Eclipse's auto complete feature, which knows about every class and method in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use *templates* for that:

First, experiment with existing templates:

- Go to the source editor and select "`foo()`".
- Open the view `General > Templates`.
- Select some template, for example, `Java > toArray` and see how it works.

Then, add your own template:

- `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates > New`.
- I think the right context should be "Java".

Another way of accesing templates is through the content assist: In the source code, in a new line, start typing the first letters of your template, then press [CTRL][SPACE]. A selector will appear with the matching templates. You may find it useful to check the checkbox "Automatically inserted" in the template definition window.

And yet another way to access them is to select a line of code and then Context Menu > Surround With.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've updated my answer to clarify what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. A quick way:

Double click or use `select enclosing element` and its cousins to select the expression you wish to wrap.  ctrl-x to temporarily cut it.  Type a few characters and ctrl-space to insert your method name and parentheses.  Finally, ctrl-v to paste what you just cut.

2. with templates - under Java Statements: ${method}(${word_selection})${cursor}

You can make a template like the one described by @LittleSanti.  If you use a fake template variable for the method name (like ${method} or ${name}) instead of a constant like `foo`, Eclipse will highlight it and let you paste or type or complete over it.  Then when you hit return or tab, it will jump the cursor to the end (the position indicated by `${cursor}`

[image: template editing screenshot]

Unfortunately I don't think Eclipse provides a "real" template variable for selecting methods in scope.  It would be nice if it would let did completion for you on methods.

Comment: From my experiments showed that the context need be _Java_ for the template to work for selections like `foo()`. Also don't get confused when the selected text (foo() here) vanishes while typing `wrap...`. It will re-appear after the template was selected. Applies to Eclipse 4.6